# What is the name of the default ggplot continuous color scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a map in R with the following code:

```
library(geobr)
shape_br <- geobr::read_state()

ggplot(shape_br)+
  geom_sf(aes(fill = code_region))+
  theme_test()
```

This example map has a particular scale of blues that is default in ggplot. I would like to use this palette in another map, but I need to specify the name of the palette/ scale. I can't find this name anywhere.

Comment: https://www.statology.org/ggplot-default-colors/

Comment: I don't think a "scale of blues" is the default - see the link from @RKeithL for how colours are assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a continuous variable is mapped to the fill or color aesthetic, the default is a blue gradient with hex color codes `low = "#132B43"` and `high = "#56B1F7"`, which can be seen by inspecting the `scale_color_gradient()`/`scale_fill_gradient()` functions or their documentation. The color gradient steps are generated by `scales::seq_gradient_pal()`.

To generate the gradient colors you can do:

```
library(scales)

n <- 12  # Number of steps in gradient
(cols <- seq_gradient_pal(low = "#132B43", high = "#56B1F7")(seq(0, 1, length.out = n)))

 [1] "#132B43" "#183652" "#1E4160" "#244C70" "#2A5880" "#306490" "#3670A0" "#3C7DB1"
 [9] "#428AC2" "#4996D3" "#4FA4E5" "#56B1F7"

show_col(cols)
```

[image]